# Maximum threads and optimal threads

Tags: c, linux, bash, mpi, openmp

I have a hybrid MPI+OpenMP code using C programming. Before I run the code, I set the threads I want to use in Linux Bash:

```
!# /bin/sh
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
```

However, if I want to use the maximum threads in this computer, how can I set in Linux bash environment like the above?

Comment: theres no hard and fast rule that i know of, for threads to processes.  The question doesnt make much sense, since some processes need more threads for messaging/gui/etc and others dont.  It really depends on the application.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, OpenMP implementations are smart enough to provide a good default for the number of threads. For instance:

- If you run an OpenMP program without any setting of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and there's no MPI at all, OpenMP will usually determine how many cores there are and use all of them.
- If there's MPI and the MPI processes are bound to a subset of the machine through process pinning, e.g., one rank per processor socket, OpenMP will inherit this subset and the implementation will automatically only use that subset.

In all those cases and most other cases, you do not need to set `OMP_NUM_THREADS` at all.

If you can share more details about what you are trying to achieve, one can provide a more detailed answer about what you need to do.

Comment: note you __must__ ask mpi to bind the MPI tasks on non overlapping cores. For example, if you simply `mpirun -np 4 ...` on a dual socket node with Open MPI, then tasks are bound to a socket, which means time sharing.